# Making the images fit in the same row regardless of window size

Tags: html, css, layout, styling, window-resize

```css
.pinkDiv {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height:290px;
  background-color: pink;
}

.miniDiv{
  width: calc(100%*100/893);
  background-color: green;
  float:left;
}

.maxiDiv {
    width: calc(100%*93/893);
    background-color: green;
    float:left;
}



img{
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  margin-top: 174px;
  float:left;

}

#queen {
  margin-top: 75px;
}
```

```html
<div class="pinkDiv">
      <div class ="miniDiv">
        <img src="./Images/pawn.png" style=" width:100%;">
      </div>
      <div class ="miniDiv">
        <img src="./Images/pawn.png" style="width:100%">
      </div>
      <div class ="miniDiv">
        <img src="./Images/pawn.png" style="width:100%">
      </div>
      <div class ="miniDiv">
        <img src="./Images/pawn.png" style="width:100%">
      </div>
      <div class ="maxiDiv">
        <img src="./Images/kwin.png" style="width:100%" id = "queen">
      </div>
      <div class ="miniDiv">
        <img src="./Images/pawn2.png" style="width:100%">
      </div>
      <div class ="miniDiv">
        <img src="./Images/pawn2.png" style="width:100%">
      </div>
      <div class ="miniDiv">
        <img src="./Images/pawn2.png" style="width:100%">
      </div>
      <div class ="miniDiv">
        <img src="./Images/pawn2.png" style="width:100%">
      </div>
</div>
```

I have about 7 divs placed in a row, each an image with background-color green. On my laptop, the row is aligned on the left. When I narrow the window size, the images fit in one row. As the window size gets even narrower, some images pile down on the bottom of the first stack. How do I get all the images to stay in a row regardless of window size?  **I've attached three screenshots, each explaining the aforementioned scenarios respectively.**

EDIT: The horizontal problem has been resolved with guidance in the comments section. This created another problem of vertical distortion of images on resizing the window.

Comment: From what's visible in the screenshots, it seems viable to make use of a CSS framework (I'd say Bulma.io works pretty good for what you need) instead of manually writing down the CSS.

Comment: Why you didn't use bootstrap???

Comment: When asking a question, there's a button that allows you to add a snippet. It makes it so much easier when asking your question, because first it lets you check if the version you sent us actually works. Second, we can edit it directly instead of trying to recreate it from scratch.

Comment: @roshnet  thank you! I'm new to CSS so I think I'll look into that when i manage to understand this one :D Thank you for the advice

Comment: @JonathonPhilipChambers Thank you for letting me know!! I knew there had to be an easier way.. just signed up on stack overflow today!!

Comment: @Swati thank you, will look into it when I get these concepts clear :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this? The key element you're missing is `width: calc(100%/7);` Just put that where you want it to be exactly a 7th of the window or container.

```css
div.blue {
  height: 30px;
  width: calc(100%/7);
  background-color: blue;
  float: left;
}
div.green {
  height: 30px;
  width: calc(100%/7);
  background-color: green;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class = "green"></div>
<div class = "blue"></div>
<div class = "green"></div>
<div class = "blue"></div>
<div class = "green"></div>
<div class = "blue"></div>
<div class = "green"></div>
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204818/discussion-on-answer-by-jonathon-philip-chambers-making-the-images-fit-in-the-sa).

Answer (score 1):

Simple responsive version.

```
<div class="pinkDiv">
  <div class="miniDiv">
    <img src="./Images/pawn.png">
  </div>
  <div class="miniDiv">
    <img src="./Images/pawn.png">
  </div>
  <div class="miniDiv">
    <img src="./Images/pawn.png">
  </div>
  <div class="miniDiv">
    <img src="./Images/pawn.png">
  </div>
  <div class="miniDiv">
    <img src="./Images/kwin.png" id="queen[![enter image description here][1]][1]">
  </div>
  <div class="miniDiv">
    <img src="./Images/pawn2.png">
  </div>
  <div class="miniDiv">
    <img src="./Images/pawn2.png">
  </div>
  <div class="miniDiv">
    <img src="./Images/pawn2.png">
  </div>
  <div class="miniDiv">
    <img src="./Images/pawn2.png">
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS Block.

```
.pinkDiv {
  background-color: #FFC0CB;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.miniDiv {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 10%;
  padding: 0;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```